# xaml border style

Tags: wpf, xaml

I create style for buttons:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#8A88E1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
```

It all OK. Now I want to write part of the style that would be looked around the ellipse boundary.

Comment: Please make your question clearer, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: i want to create ellipse with border around it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erno beat me to the answer, but here's an example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#8A88E1"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Grid>
          <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="..." StrokeThickness="..." />
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

You should be able to bind the `Stroke` to the parent `BorderBrush` but I haven't tested it: `Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"`. However, you won't be able to directly bind `StrokeThickness` to the parent `BorderThickness` as they're two different types (`Ellipse.StrokeThickness` is uniform and a simple `double` value whereas `Button.BorderThickness` is of type `Thickness`.).

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1. Set the Stroke and StrokeThickness of the ellipse or
2. Add a template to the border and use an ellipse in the template.

Let me know if you need help with these.